# Can I make postgres only listen on a single hostname?

Tags: postgresql, reverse-proxy

Obviously I could listen on a particular IP address, but is it possible to listen on a particular hostname? Specifically, if example1.com and example2.com both point to my server with IP address (say) 12.34.56.78, is it possible to proxy connections to example1.com:5432 to my postgres db, but have connections to example2.com:5432 be rejected?

I have a feeling the hostname is not passed in the initial connection, so it would be impossible to do what can be done with HTTP(S) (e.g. Nginx server block, Caddy, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. The database server never sees the host name the client used. Domain Name Service (DNS) resolution of a host name to an IP address has to happen *before* the server can be contacted.

You will have to use two different IP addresses, for example by defining a second, virtual IP address for the server. You don't need to have a second network card.